# How to define bounds in a projected space from which we want to also recover

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projective-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

Let's assume we have an "n" dimensional space defined within a hyper-cube bounds and can project points in this space to a lower "m" dimensional one by multiplying it with a matrix of n*m.

Within the low dimensional space I want to apply a search algorithm after which I get a recommendation in this low dimensional space and want to map this recommendation back to the original n dimensional space.

Needless to say, the solution for mapping this low dimensional point to the high dimensional one is not unique. Nevertheless, for this I apply an optimization to find an input of high dimensional space for which the projection will be what I was recommended with in the low dimensional one.

[image]

However, I am not sure how to define the bounds within the low dimensional search space so that this task is done in a sensible way.

For example, as shown in the above figure a 2 dimensional plane can be projected on a 1 dimensional line defined by a vector.

In addition, this bound could possibly be defined in two ways which is described by the below figure in contrast to the above one about which I appreciate your recommendations and thoughts.

For example, does it make sense to project the corners and take the most distant ones as bounds? If so, how do I do it in a high dimensional setting!
[image]

Comment: An idea : consider the hypersphere circumscribed to the hypercube : its projection is much simpler than the projection of the hypercube because it is a circle (proj. on $\mathbb{R}^2$) or a sphere (proj. on $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: @JeanMarie in that case I neglect a part of the hypercube space, right? But I can also consider this if I define a hypersphere instead of hypercube in the first place since it makes things way easier or possible

Comment: No risk to neglect a part of the hypercube because property "being included into" is preserved by projection.

Comment: @JeanMarie I see now, by circumscribed you meant the hyper-cube is inside the hypersphere. In that case my recovery to high dimensional space may fall outside of the hypercube, if I understand correctly. It is still a good solution if my original problem is defined in a hyper sphere. The algorithm that also looks for the recovery could perhaps also make it possible to be inside the hypercube